# Accessing class property always returns false in P5JS

Tags: javascript, class, p5.js

I have a game in P5.JS that i want to pause. Most of my code is in a `class`. This class has a `isPaused` field that is set to `false` in the constructor. Now, i have a button that flips this value, like this:
`this.buttonP.mousePressed(function () {this.isPaused = !this.isPaused;});`. When i print the value from inside the class, the value is flipped appropriately. However, when I try to access the `isPaused` property from the draw function, which is in the primary.js file, the value is always false.
Here's part of the code:

```
let game;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(scale * factor + 1000, scale * factor);
    game = new CellularAutomaton(RULESETS.DAY_AND_NIGHT, 90, 0);
    game.setupButton();
    game.initField();
}

function draw() {
    if (!game.isPaused){
        game.updateField();
    }
}

class CellularAutomaton
{
    generation = 0;
    field = [];
    colorfield = [];
    born = [];
    survive = [];
    scale = 0;
    active = 0;
    factor = 15;
    movement = 0;
    isPaused;
    buttonR;
    buttomP;

    constructor(rule, scale, movement)
    {
        var tempborn = rule.split('/')[0];
        var tempsurvive = rule.split('/')[1];
        this.born = tempborn.split('');
        this.survive = tempsurvive.split('');
        this.born.shift();
        this.survive.shift();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.born.length; i++) this.born[i] = +this.born[i];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.survive.length; i++) this.survive[i] = +this.survive[i];
        this.scale = scale;
        this.movement = movement;
        this.isPaused = false;
    }
    setupButton(){
        this.buttonP = createButton('Pause');
        this.buttonP.position(this.scale * this.factor + 100, 500)
        this.buttonP.size(width/8 + 30, height/8);
        this.buttonP.mousePressed(function () {this.isPaused = !this.isPaused;});
        this.buttonP.style('background-color', color(0,0,255));
        this.buttonP.style('font-size', 100)
    
        this.buttonR = createButton('Restart');
        this.buttonR.position(this.scale * this.factor + 500, 500)
        this.buttonR.size(width/8 + 30, height/8);
        this.buttonR.mousePressed(this.initField);
        this.buttonR.style('background-color', color(0,0,255));
        this.buttonR.style('font-size', 100)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `function` create a new scope with its proper context so the `this` used in the function is not referring the class context anymore. You should use an anonymous function since they operate in the enclosing scope context (the class here) or save the class context inside a variable like this :

```js
// create a new context, not accessing this.isPaused from class anymore
this.buttonP.mousePressed(function () {this.isPaused = !this.isPaused;});

// dos not create a new context then can access isPaused from current class context
this.buttonP.mousePressed() => this.isPaused = !this.isPaused;);

// or
const that = this;
this.buttonP.mousePressed(function () {that.isPaused = !that.isPaused;});
```

[More reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: This works, thank you. Another thing - you can also run functions like that are defined in the class like this:
`this.buttonR.mousePressed(() => this.initField());`